# How to enable Balloon notification in windows7 through java code

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

Is there some way to enable the balloon notification in Windows 7 through JAVA code? I am talking about the notification bubbles that pop up above the notification area in the taskbar.

The code which i wrote is working fine for windowsXP. Please let me know how to get in windows7. Any setting changes required for enable in windows7..??

Thanks,
Sharab

Comment: What's the code for Windows XP? How is it not working on Windows 7?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html